# TFS 2017 uninstalled itself after system updates

Tags: tfs

We upgraded on-premise TFS to TFS 2017 update 3 (product version: 15.117.27024.0) on a new Windows 2016 server on 9/21/2018.  It worked perfectly.

On 10/10/2018 around 12:40am, a KB4462917 was installed on server. A new TFS product version, 15.117.27414.0, was installed around the same time. However, it didn't finish the mini-upgrade totally, and the TFS App Tier was removed. From the TFS log, I can see a command '/uninstall:ALL' was issued around the time. The result was that TFS website was removed and we cannot use TFS website. I had to configure installed feature at the app tier using TFS admin console.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: So, can you normally access the TFS site after the configuration?  You can check the entire upgrade log and the systems event logs to track the problems...

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT From the logs in TFS console and windows event log, I can see a newer mini version of TFS (15.117.27414.0) was installed. This mini newer TFS version caused the uninstallation of older version (15.117.27024.0) of TFS, but it didn't proceed to reconfigure the installed feature, and the tfs website with port 8080 was removed from IIS. So we basically didn't have the App Tier. My solution was to reconfigure the App Tier. It worked. To answer your question, yes, I access TFS website after re-configured app tier.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT  But I really try to understand why because I don't want to do this re-configuration after every mid-night system update.

Comment: Have not encountered a similar situation, the only thing we can do is checking the logs...